# Sharing VirtualBox VM and Docker Container network

Tags: docker, networking, virtualbox

I have an headless server with VirtualBox. It run multiple virtual machines. One of them is a web proxy. It redirect external access to the right VM in function of the subdomain. Those VMs are communicating between them with internal network (intnet).

I would like to add some docker container to this configuration. How could I successfully create a network shared between my docker containers and this proxy VM ?

I tried to create a bridge network with docker `docker network create my_net` and then connect the VM with a additional network card in 'bridged' mode.
With this config `ping` works but **not the actual connection**. It isn't impossible to display the web page into a browser.

Am I missing some configuration here ? Also, is it a good practice to connect one VM to a docker network ?

Answer (score 0):

Run the containers on one of the VMs.  Use a totally normal Docker setup here: create a network for inter-container communication but don't configure it, and completely ignore the container-private network details and IP addresses.

When you use the `docker run -p` option, that will publish a container's port on its VM's network interface(s).  From that point, other VMs can call the published port using that VM's IP address, just as if it were a non-container process running on the VM.  Conversely, containers should be able to make outbound calls to the other VMs without special setup.

Comment: That is exactly what I don't want to do. The idea is to have the containers running directly on the host to let docker manage the ram itself and avoid the VM ram limitation.

Comment: If the VMs have a network route to contact the host, you can do the same thing running Docker outside the VM; use the host's IP address to reach the `docker run -p` published ports.

Comment: The server have multiple applications that use multiple ports and it will be a nightmare to maintain the redirect of all those ports.